Selecting all neighbors of a set of nodes in a graph?
I have this network in R:
library(igraph)

set.seed(123)
n <- 20
g <- sample_gnm(n, m = n * 2, directed = FALSE)
while (!is_connected(g)) {
    components <- components(g)
    for (i in 2:components$no) {
        from <- sample(which(components$membership == i), 1)
        to <- sample(which(components$membership == 1), 1)
        g <- add_edges(g, c(from, to))
    }
}
g <- simplify(g, remove.multiple = FALSE, remove.loops = TRUE)
V(g)$weight <- runif(vcount(g))

V(g)$color <- "white"


I wrote some R code that simulates the following process:

iteration 1: a single random node is selected (a), and all 1st degree neighbors (b) of this node are selected
iteration 2: a single random node (c) is selected from (b), all  1st degree neighbors of (d) are selected (everything else from the previous iteration is deselected)
iteration 3: a single random node (e) is selected from (d), all 1st degree  neighbors of (e) are selected (everything else from the previous iteration is deselected)
etc

Here is the simulation:
plot_graph <- function(graph, layout, current_node, current_neighbors, iteration) {
    vertex_colors <- rep("white", vcount(graph))
    vertex_colors[current_neighbors] <- "lightblue"
    vertex_colors[current_node] <- "yellow"
    
    edge_colors <- rep("gray", ecount(graph))
    edge_colors[incident(graph, current_node, mode="all")] <- "blue"
    
    plot(graph, layout = layout, vertex.color = vertex_colors, edge.color = edge_colors,
         edge.arrow.size = 0.1, vertex.label = V(graph)$name, vertex.size = 15,
         vertex.label.color = "black", edge.curved = 0,
         main = paste("Iteration:", iteration, "- Current Node:", V(graph)$name[current_node]))
    
    legend("topright", legend = c("Other Nodes", "Current Node", "Neighbors"),
           fill = c("white", "yellow", "lightblue"), border = "black", cex = 0.8)
}

traverse_graph <- function(graph, num_iterations = 100) {
    visited <- numeric(vcount(graph))
    layout <- layout_with_fr(graph)  # Calculate layout once
    
    current_node <- sample(1:vcount(graph), 1)  
    previous_node <- NA
    
    comm_df <- data.frame(
        iteration = integer(),
        from_node = integer(),
        to_node = integer(),
        neighbors = character(),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    
    for (iteration in 1:num_iterations) {
        visited[current_node] <- visited[current_node] + 1
        current_neighbors <- neighbors(graph, current_node)
        
        cat(sprintf("Iteration %d : node %s -> node %d\n", 
                    iteration, 
                    ifelse(is.na(previous_node), "START", as.character(previous_node)), 
                    current_node))
        
        cat("Current node neighbors:", paste(current_neighbors, collapse = ", "), "\n\n")
        
        comm_df <- rbind(comm_df, data.frame(
            iteration = iteration,
            from_node = ifelse(is.na(previous_node), NA, previous_node),
            to_node = current_node,
            neighbors = paste(current_neighbors, collapse = ", "),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        ))
        
        plot_graph(graph, layout, current_node, current_neighbors, iteration)
        Sys.sleep(0.5)  
        
        previous_node <- current_node
        current_node <- sample(current_neighbors, 1)  # Randomly select next node from neighbors
    }
    
    return(list(visited = visited, comm_df = comm_df))

write.csv(result$comm_df, "communication_log.csv", row.names = FALSE)

I run the simulation like this- everything works well!:
result <- traverse_graph(g, 100)


I am trying to modify this R code to accomplish the following:

iteration 1: a single random node is selected (a), and all 1st degree neighbors of (a) are selected (b)
iteration 2: all nodes in (b) are selected and all 1st degree neighbors of all nodes in (b) are selected (c) (everything else from the previous iteration is deselected)
iteration 3: all nodes in (c) are selected and all 1st degree neighbors of all nodes in (c) are selected (d) (everything else from previous iteration is deselected)
etc

I tried the following logic to reset colors (i.e. deselection) and select all neighbors using the following logic:
plot_graph <- function(graph, layout, current_nodes, current_neighbors, iteration) {
    vertex_colors <- rep("white", vcount(graph))
    vertex_colors[current_neighbors] <- "lightblue"
    vertex_colors[current_nodes] <- "yellow"
    
    edge_colors <- rep("gray", ecount(graph))
    for (node in current_nodes) {
        edge_colors[incident(graph, node, mode="all")] <- "blue"
    }
    
    plot(graph, layout = layout, vertex.color = vertex_colors, edge.color = edge_colors,
         edge.arrow.size = 0.1, vertex.label = V(graph)$name, vertex.size = 15,
         vertex.label.color = "black", edge.curved = 0,
         main = paste("Iteration:", iteration, "- Current Nodes:", paste(V(graph)$name[current_nodes], collapse = ", ")))
    
    legend("topright", legend = c("Other Nodes", "Current Nodes", "Neighbors"),
           fill = c("white", "yellow", "lightblue"), border = "black", cex = 0.8)
}

traverse_graph <- function(graph, num_iterations = 100) {
    visited <- numeric(vcount(graph))
    layout <- layout_with_fr(graph)  
    
    current_nodes <- sample(1:vcount(graph), 1)  
    
    comm_df <- data.frame(
        iteration = integer(),
        current_nodes = character(),
        neighbors = character(),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    
    for (iteration in 1:num_iterations) {
        visited[current_nodes] <- visited[current_nodes] + 1
        current_neighbors <- unique(unlist(sapply(current_nodes, function(node) neighbors(graph, node))))
        current_neighbors <- setdiff(current_neighbors, current_nodes)  
        
        cat(sprintf("Iteration %d\n", iteration))
        cat("Current nodes:", paste(current_nodes, collapse = ", "), "\n")
        cat("Current node neighbors:", paste(current_neighbors, collapse = ", "), "\n\n")
        
        comm_df <- rbind(comm_df, data.frame(
            iteration = iteration,
            current_nodes = paste(current_nodes, collapse = ", "),
            neighbors = paste(current_neighbors, collapse = ", "),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        ))
        
        plot_graph(graph, layout, current_nodes, current_neighbors, iteration)
        Sys.sleep(0.5)  
        
        current_nodes <- c(current_nodes, current_neighbors)  
    }
    
    return(list(visited = visited, comm_df = comm_df))
}


 result <- traverse_graph(g, 10)  

The problem with this logic is that after a few iterations, all nodes end up being selected in yellow (when there should still be white nodes):

How can I fix this?

In your second bullet point, you said: " all 1st degree neighbors of (d) are selected..." but (d) isn't defined yet. I think you need to omit the word "of" here. The same for the third bullet point (delete the word "of"?)

The nodes from the previous iteration (which you want to deselect and think should be white) are also neighbors of the current iteration and are thus yellow.  Nothing can ever become white again because it is always a neighbor of the current round.

I refactored your code a bit (using recursion instead of loops) and used dedicated functions from igraph (which avoid some of your loops):
library(glue)
library(dplyr)
library(cli)

layout <- layout_with_fr(g)
plot_graph <- function(graph, current_nodes, neighbor_nodes, title = "", 
                       graph_layout = layout) {
  vc <- rep("white", vcount(graph))
  vc[as_ids(neighbor_nodes)] <- "lightblue"
  vc[as_ids(current_nodes)] <- "yellow"
  
  ec <- rep("gray", ecount(graph))
  ec[as_ids(do.call(c, incident_edges(graph, current_nodes)))] <- "blue"
  
  plot(graph, layout = graph_layout, vertex.color = vc, edge.color = ec,
       edge.arrow.size = 0.1, vertex.label = V(graph)$name, vertex.size = 15,
       vertex.label.color = "black", edge.curved = 0,
       main = title)
  
  legend("topright", legend = c("Other Nodes", "Current Node", "Neighbors"),
         fill = c("white", "yellow", "lightblue"), border = "black", cex = 0.8)
}

visit_graph <- function(graph, max_iteration = 100, delay = .5) {
  traverse <- function(graph, current_nodes, iteration) {
    res <- NULL
    if (iteration <= max_iteration) {
      ## All 1st degree neighbors of the current_nodes
      adj <- adjacent_vertices(graph, current_nodes)
      if (length(adj) == 1) {
        ## add a dummy second element such that union will work
        adj <- c(adj, list(NULL))
      }
      nbs <- do.call(igraph::union, adj)
      nbs <- difference(nbs, current_nodes)
      cli_h1("Iteration {iteration}")
      cli_alert_info("Current Node{?s}: {.field {as.character(as_ids(current_nodes))}}")
      cli_alert_info("All Neighbor{?s}: {.field {as.character(as_ids(nbs))}}")
      plot_graph(graph, current_nodes, nbs, title = glue("Iteration {iteration}")
      Sys.sleep(delay)
      res <- tibble(
        iteration = iteration,
        from_node = paste(as_ids(current_nodes), collapse = ", "),
        to_nodes = paste(as_ids(nbs), collapse = ", ")
      )
      res <- bind_rows(res, Recall(graph, nbs, iteration + 1L))
    }
    res
  }
  traverse(graph, sample(V(g), 1L), 1L)
}

res <- visit_graph(g, 10)

BUT: As you are selecting all the neighbors, at some point the neighbors of these neighbors will simply span the whole graph. At this moment we reahc an alternating state: we select all neighbors (except the currently selected ones) and we reverse this selection in the next iteration.
But maybe I misunderstood your requirements about "deselecting". I read it as: "select all neighbors which are not anyways already in the current nodes".


@thotal: thank you for your answer! I think now I understand the problem - you are correct, we we will reach a point no node will be white colored...

I don't have fancy visualization here, but hope the result is the thing you want
res <- list()
prev <- src <- sample.int(vcount(g), 1)
repeat {
    if (length(src) == 0) break
    nbs <- setdiff(unlist(neighborhood(g, nodes = src, mindist = 1)), prev)
    prev <- src
    res[[length(res) + 1]] <- list(
        current_node = src,
        unvisited_neighbors = nbs
    )
    src <- nbs
}

such that
> res
[[1]]
[[1]]$current_node
[1] 8

[[1]]$unvisited_neighbors
[1]  1  4  5 14 15


[[2]]
[[2]]$current_node
[1]  1  4  5 14 15

[[2]]$unvisited_neighbors
 [1]  3  5  9 10 14 15 17 19  1  2 20  4  6 11 12


[[3]]
[[3]]$current_node
 [1]  3  5  9 10 14 15 17 19  1  2 20  4  6 11 12

[[3]]$unvisited_neighbors
 [1] 17  2  8  9 20  6 11  7 12  3 18 16 10 13 19


[[4]]
[[4]]$current_node
 [1] 17  2  8  9 20  6 11  7 12  3 18 16 10 13 19

[[4]]$unvisited_neighbors
[1]  7 18 13 16


[[5]]
[[5]]$current_node
[1]  7 18 13 16

[[5]]$unvisited_neighbors
integer(0)

